# How to edit the Android.manifest.template.xml file to receive Push Notifications

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

Let me restructure this question. My objective is try and get some assistance with setting up Push Notifications on a cross-platform Delphi App (iOS & Android). I initially followed a blog post by Sarina Du Pont via Embarcadero [here](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/sarinadupont/2014/04/16/remote-push-notifications-on-android-with-rad-studio-xe6/#comment-5934).

I gather that you have to adjust your Android.manifest.template.xml file with the additional permission entries, as explained quite well via [this](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Creating_the_Application) blog post. However, having done this exactly, my Android app still does not receive any Push Notifications. I have included my Android manifest template file here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    package="%package%"

    android:versionCode="%versionCode%"

    android:versionName="%versionName%">


<!-- This is the platform API where NativeActivity was introduced. -->

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="%minSdkVersion%" />
```

```
<!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<!--
 Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages.

 NOTE: the permission *must* be called PACKAGE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE,
 where PACKAGE is the application's package name.
-->
<permission android:name="%package%.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="%package%.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission
android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<application android:persistent="%persistent%"

    android:restoreAnyVersion="%restoreAnyVersion%"

    android:label="%label%"

    android:installLocation="%installLocation%"

    android:debuggable="%debuggable%"

    android:largeHeap="%largeHeap%"

     android:icon="%icon%"

     android:theme="@style/MyTheme.NoTitleBar.SplashWindow">

    <!-- Our activity is a subclass of the built-in NativeActivity framework class.

         This will take care of integrating with our NDK code. -->

    <activity android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity"

            android:label="%activityLabel%"

            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">

        <!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of our .so -->

        <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"

            android:value="%libNameValue%" />

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>
    <receiver
          android:name="com.embarcadero.gcm.notifications.GCMNotification" android:exported="true"
          android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
              <category android:name="%package%" />
           </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.embarcadero.gcm.notifications.GCMIntentService" />


    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.notifications.FMXNotificationAlarm" />

</application>
```

Have I done something wrong?

Comment: You should *always* add the **delphi** tag to your Delphi related questions. If you ever wonder about low attention to your question, that is the reason. (the same with all tags containing a special version)

Answer (score 2):

Read the tutorial again more carefully, it gives you the download link:

> On platforms that do not include OpenSSL libraries, such as iOS, you will need to download [OpenSSL libraries](http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/).

If you follow that link, you will see an [`OpenSSLStaticLibs.7z`](http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/OpenSSLStaticLibs.7z) file, which contains the 2 `.a` files you are looking for.

Comment: Yip, this is a "Here's your sign" moment for me then... LOL!